# RMagick Masking - different background different result

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick, image-masking

I have 2 t-shirt images, the color are black and pink. i want to blend it with android logo. on the black t-shirt the result was great. but on the pink one, android image is to bright.

here's my code

```
    tshirt = Magick::Image.read("/Volumes/Work/rmagick/cacat.png").first

    canvas = Magick::Image.new(tshirt.rows, tshirt.columns) do |c|
        c.background_color = "none"
    end

    img = Magick::Image.read("/Volumes/Work/rmagick/android_logo2.png").first
    img = img.resize_to_fit(250)

    # # contour
    contour = img.composite!(canvas, Magick::CenterGravity, Magick::InCompositeOp)
    img = Magick::Image.read("/Volumes/Work/rmagick/android_logo2.png").first
    img = img.resize_to_fit(250)

    contour = contour.composite!(img, Magick::CenterGravity, Magick::AddCompositeOp)

    tshirt = tshirt.composite!(contour, 295,250, Magick::PlusCompositeOp)

    tshirt.write('/Volumes/Work/jadi.png')
```

and here's the result

[image: black]

[image: pink]

so how can i make android image is like when it on the black t-shirt. which of my code that i should change ?

Comment: I don't speak Ruby, but try changing `Magick::PlusCompositeOp` for something else - maybe something with `Overlay` or `Blend` in its name.

Comment: its okay if you have only imagemagick commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of the blending modes with:

```
identify -list compose
```

So, you can do this and see which one suits your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash
for blend in $(identify -list compose|grep -v Blur ); do 
  convert -gravity center -label "$blend" tshirt.png android.png -compose $blend -composite miff:-
done | montage - -tile 5x result.png
```

[image]